# UTF-8 compatible truncate function

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

Anybody run into this problem for complex Latin characters, such as Vietnamese?

```
    function truncate($str, $length, $append = '…') {
      $strLength = mb_strlen($str);

      if ($strLength <= $length) {
         return $str;
      }

      return mb_substr($str, 0, $length) . $append;
    }

echo truncate('Bà Rịa - Vũng Tàu!', 14);
```

outputs:

Bà Rịa - V�…

http://codepad.viper-7.com/GOZFB0

I need some help to make it cut at the character, but I'm not even sure what is going on behind the scenes here.

Comment: Does mb_internal_encoding() return the character set that you are using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [mb_strimwidth](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strimwidth.php) (PHP Documentation):

```
echo mb_strimwidth("Hello World", 0, 10, "...");
```

---

Or a custom function like [Multibyte String Truncate for Smarty](http://www.guyrutenberg.com/2007/12/04/multibyte-string-truncate-modifier-for-smarty-mb_truncate/):

```
mb_truncate($string, $length = 80, $etc = '...', $charset='UTF-8',
                                  $break_words = false, $middle = false)
{
    if ($length == 0)
        return '';

    if (strlen($string) > $length) {
        $length -= min($length, strlen($etc));
        if (!$break_words && !$middle) {
            $string = preg_replace('/\s+?(\S+)?$/', '', mb_substr($string, 0, $length+1, $charset));
        }
        if(!$middle) {
            return mb_substr($string, 0, $length, $charset) . $etc;
        } else {
            return mb_substr($string, 0, $length/2, $charset) . $etc . mb_substr($string, -$length/2, $charset);
        }
    } else {
        return $string;
    }
}
```

Comment: `echo mb_strimwidth("Hello World", 0, 10, "...",'UTF-8');` works, however. I can't seem to get the default character set to be UTF-8, no matter what I do! Thanks though :)

Comment: @RVWard can't win them all! At least it works for you if you specify the character set :)

Answer (score -1):

Be sure to perform necessary Unicode normalization to ensure each character correspond to a single codepoint.

[Vietnamese Unicode FAQs](http://vietunicode.sourceforge.net/)