# How to truncate an UTF8 string in PHP?

Tags: php, string, utf-8, truncate

I have some strings in my PHP code that need to be truncated if they are too long.

For example if a text is something like this:

> Hi, I would like to tell you how wonderful this is.

It would replace it with this:

> Hi, I would like to ...

For that I've done a simple `substr`. The problem is that in UTF8 some characters are actually two characters long. And I've had some problems with a character being cut in the middle: For example, when I try to insert the modified string in the database, it crashes.

Here is my current function:

```
static function short($string, $max = 255){
   if(strlen($string) >= $max){
       $string = substr($string, 0, $max - 5).'...';
   } return $string;
}
```

Would someone know a way to make this function work even for UTF8 characters?

Comment: have a look at `https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!unicode.inc/function/truncate_utf8/7`

Comment: possible duplicate of [UTF-8 compatible truncate function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288875/utf-8-compatible-truncate-function)

Comment: You might find [`s($str)->truncate($length)`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str/blob/8fd0c608d5496d43adaa899642c1cce047e076dc/src/Str.php#L233) and [`s($str)->truncateSafely($length)`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str/blob/8fd0c608d5496d43adaa899642c1cce047e076dc/src/Str.php#L246) helpful, as found in [this standalone library](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str). Both versions are Unicode-safe. The latter does not break words.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Everything you need is mb_strimwidth() : http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strimwidth.php

Example:

```
mb_strimwidth('Hi, I would like to tell you how wonderful this is.',0,15,'...','utf-8');
```

Comment: @trejder No, it isn't. *The initial version of this article was claiming that mb_strimwidth() is deprecated in PHP 7.2 and that this deprecation was a source of described problem. It turned out that mb_strimwidth() is (of course!) not deprecated in PHP 7.2.*

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Correct! I'm removing my comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

try with [`mb_substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php) :

```
static function short($string, $max = 255){
   if(mb_strlen($string, 'utf-8') >= $max){
       $string = mb_substr($string, 0, $max - 5, 'utf-8').'...';
   } return $string;
}
```

Comment: @deceze - you are right, thx for pointing that out - i corrected the copy/pasted code